# Cypress : How to use variables inside each function

Tags: cypress

I have a local variable that I am trying to access within the  **each** function as below :

```
var i = 0
cy.get('body').then((body) => {
      cy
        .get('.classname')
        .each(($element) => {
       
       cy.log(i) //returns empty value
       ///ACCESS THE "i" variable here
    }
   }
```

How can the local variable be accessed inside the each function? Is there a restriction on the scope of the variables inside the each function

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `i` variable inside the `.each()` but `cy.log()` will capture the initial value only.

`console.log` will show you the current value.

```js
const texts = ['abc', '123']
cy.get('body').then((body) => {
  cy.get('.classname')
    .each(($element, i) => {
       cy.wrap($element).should('contain.text', texts[i])
    }
  }
```

Comment: The code block that was written in the original question is a short form of how I wanted to access...The actual way that I wanted to do is **cy.wrap(element).should('contain.text',array[i])** (where array is a global array defined) So using cy.log or console.log does not actually solve the problem

Comment: You could access `i` from the `.each()` parameter list

Comment: The **i** increments everytime on every element that is found in the **each** block. But I want the **i** to remain constant

Comment: Yeah, that was the impression from the question - but `cy.wrap(element).should('contain.text',array[i])` gives the impression you want to compare each element text with a different array member.

Comment: Oops, the actual problem was to compare each element that is wrapped in the each block by iterating through each element in the array list. So the **i** should remain constant here

Comment: If `i` remains constant, then it will compare each element text to the first array element ("abc" in my sample). I thought you would want to compare 1st element to "abc", 2nd element to "123", etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247142/discussion-between-user-and-fody).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain off `each` to cy. [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Syntax)

You can use it like this:

```js
var i = 0
cy.get('selector').each(($ele) => {
  cy.log(i) //prints 0
})
```